# Running Multiple distinct Services on a single server process

Tags: design, architecture, clean-code, architectural-patterns, maintainability

I am working on a java server, which has a bunch of seemingly distinct "services".
A lot of which are just effectively classes. From a software architecture point of view I wonder what the opinion is on such a setup. Is there any advantage to be gained by splitting the related services off into their own server? Or is the pain involved in maintaining multiple processes not worth it. I realize the answer very well might be that "it depends". However I was hoping to maybe establish some general guidelines/principles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decide whether to adopt a micro services approach](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/338328/how-to-decide-whether-to-adopt-a-micro-services-approach)

Comment: As you expected,  _it depends_. In this case, it depends on very specific circumstances (expected load, critical nature of availability, how to balance hardware cost vs developer cost vs maintenance cost vs runtime performance, expected lifetime of services, frequent updates, how to handle outages and new releases, ...) There's just so much ground to cover that it can't really be one in a Q&A format. The general idea is that your company needs to decide whether the extra cost is worth the improvement in runtime performance and reliability.